# How to get subnet_id from terraform when subnets created with for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Problem Statement**: Trying to get subnet id from subnets created with `for_each` in terraform

**My terraform.tfvars.json:**

```
"subnets" : {
        "Dev" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.1.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Stage" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.2.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ],
        "Prod" :
        [  
        {"gw_snet":{
          "name"                 : "GatewaySubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.1.0/24"]
        },
        "dns-snet" : {
          "name"                 : "InboundDNSSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.2.0/24"]
        },
        "common_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "Common",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.3.0/24"]
        },
        "clientdata_snet" : {
          "name"                 : "ClientDataSubnet",
          "address_prefixes"     : ["10.3.4.0/20"]
        }}
        ]
      }
```

**my Main.tf**

```
locals {
   net_subnets = merge([
    for env, network in var.subnets : {
      for k, v in network[0] :
      "${k}-${v.name}" => {
        subnet_name      = v.name
        address_prefixes = v.address_prefixes
      } if env == "${var.env}"
  }]...)
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each = {for k,v in var.vnet_address_space: k=>v if k == "${var.env}"}
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  address_space       = each.value
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  for_each             = local.net_subnets
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[var.env].name  
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  service_endpoints    = var.service_endpoints
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "nsg-vnet-orpcb-hub-${var.env}-we-indoundDNS"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.value].id   
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
```

Now Issue I am getting when I try to fetch `subnet_id` at below line while assoicating nsg to particularsubnet ( I dont want to associate nsg to all subnet but rather only one)

```
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.value].id   

**Error:**

      Error: each.value cannot be used in this context
│ 
│   on main.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc":
│  120:   subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.value].id   
│ 
│ A reference to "each.value" has been used in a context in which it unavailable, such as when the configuration no longer contains the value in its "`for_each`" expression. Remove this reference to each.value in your configuration to work around this error.
```

In my above case, I need to attach this nsg only to specific subnet for example "`ClientDataSubnet`" only, how to refer this value and get that subnets' id

How to see / print how my subnet information getting stored when I use `for_each` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `each.value` variable is only available inside a resource block with a `for_each` meta argument.

You are currently trying to create a single `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` resource, but it appears you need to create a `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` for each subnet. To do that you need to add a `for_each` meta argument to the `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` resource block:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  for_each                  = local.net_subnets
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[each.value].id   
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}
```

Comment: Actually in my case though, I have created multiple subnets, I need to associate network security group to only one specific subnet, how to refer to specific subnet in subnet_id ? and also I will have some more resources to be created in ClientDataSubnet only.. In that scenario I am getting challenge to refer to instance of that subnet. I tried like  `subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[ClientDataSubnet].id`   it didnt work

Comment: And what was the error in that case?

Comment: @MarkoE I get  this one `on main.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc":
│  120:   subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnet[ClientDataSubnet].id  
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.`

Comment: were you able to figure this out?  i also would like to know how to refer to a subnet resource by a string name